# MS Excel: Taking a cell value as Column number, and then offset-ting it

Tags: excel-formula

I've tried searching for this query and haven't really been able to get my head around Indirect, Offset, Address and the various look up other functions.

I have a value such as `AW` in a cell (say in `A1`). Using `formula =INDIRECT($A$1 & ROW())` in cell `A3`, I'm able to get the value in `AW3`. However, I wish to now retrieve the value which is 1 column before `AW`. Hence, how can I derive the column/row reference which is `-1` from what I get in `A1` (`AW` in this example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT($A$1 & ROW()), 0, -1)
```

No way to check it in excel right now, i leave the testing to you.